# after changing the wordpress adress and site address in localhost xampp then it not working anymore

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in creating a website using wordpress. I am using xampp to create a local wordpress website and my website run under: **localhost/mysite**. I want to import my local website to my live website **https://vsaftest.wordpress.com/** by going to the setting of my local website and then changed the **wordpress Address** and **site address** from **http://localhost/mysite** to https://vsaftest.wordpress.com/. After that then I can not access to my local site using http://localhost/mysite anymore, and inside the website https://vsaftest.wordpress.com/ there is nothing there also. I know that I made a mistake here but then anyone can help me how can I change back so that I can access my site from localhost :(

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Wordpress before, but going *purely* from your desription, you seem to think that changing a setting on and *for* your **local machine** will somehow affect the settings on a **remote machine**.

> and inside the website https://vsaftest.wordpress.com/ there is nothing there also

But was there nothing there *beforehand* either? In other words; Nothing's changed?

I think the reason you cannot view your local site anymore is precisely because you made the change you said you did. Instead of its changing the **remote** machine (which it probably doesn't do...I don't do WP dev, so I don't know *for sure*) it changed your **local** machine.

Can you not just change **wordpress Address** and **site address** on your local site *back to* what it was before?

Comment: hi, that what I mean, I would like to change back the **wordpress Address** and **site address** back to my local site so that i can access it via localhost/mysite like it was before but have no idea how to change it

Comment: Yes I see. Have you googled for "Xampp change localhost"? If you had, you would have found [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847392/how-to-change-xampp-localhost-to-another-folder-outside-xampp-folder) which describes what to do for both Ubuntu and Windows (see about halfway down).

Answer (score 0):

There are many pitfalls one might encounter when moving a Wordpress website from a local development environment to production. Here are the main things to remember and look out for.

### Htaccess

When developing in Xampp it's very common to include the website's directory name in the .htaccess' `RewriteBase` and `RewriteRule`. Assuming your production website will be situated in the root directory you'll want to remove the directory references from your .htaccess file.
For example your development .htaccess file might look like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But in production you'll need to adjust it to look like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

One good development practice you can adopt is creating .live and .dev htaccess files. Create .htaccess.dev and .htaccess.live files and store your development and production htaccess data in them respectively. Your real .htaccess file will then contain the current active data and you can easily copy/paste from the .dev and .live files to it if needed.

### Database

When you move a Wordpress website to production you must also create a production database for it. Make sure the database created has the same collation as the development one and that the database credentials in your `wp-config.php` file are updated to reflect the production database user, password, etc. Remember that if your `WP_DEBUG` variable is not set to true database errors will not be shown if a database connection error occurred in your production website. Because of that database errors in production more often than not lead to a "white screen of death".

Another thing one must make sure (and you already mentioned in your question) is that the `siteurl` and `homeurl` keys in your `wp_options` table are updated to reflect the production website url. In case multiple domains exist (for example .com and .co) one can enforce the correct url by defining the `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOMEURL` constants dynamically within the wp-config.php file.

### PHP version

Last but not least, make sure the PHP version required for your website is compatible with the production server's PHP version. 2017 is a transitional year in terms of PHP support. Whereas Xampp already supports PHP 7 sadly many servers still do not.