# Brackets php live view

Tags: php, adobe-brackets

I recently switched over to brackets as my main coding platform.  I am creating a live chat room with a login page using php.  Is there any way to set up a live view for php in brackets the same way html is set up?  I have the sql and everything already done.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get PHP working in Brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950211/how-to-get-php-working-in-brackets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your own local server is already running. Then, go to **File -> Settings**, and then enter the URL that corresponds to the *root* folder of your project.

Take a [look](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#live-preview) at the details and limitations of using live preview with your own backend.