# Apigility API path is not correct when installed with XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp, laminas-api-tools

I've installed Apigility on my CENTOS box which has XAMPP installed to handle my web services. After successfully installing Apigility I can access the admin ui by going to `http://00.111.222.33/apigility/public/`, which is fine for the ui panel, but when I create an RPC api my path is `http://00.111.222.33/apigility/public/ping` which is not desirable. I'd like the path to be `http://00.111.222.33/ping` like how the Apigility tutorials show as an example.

My first thought is to configure the .htaccess rules, but not sure if that's what I should do.

Is installing Apigility in the htdocs the correct place?

Does Apigility have a place to configure the "pretty url"?

Not sure if the port has anything to do with things, but my CENTOS is configured to listen to port 5757.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make public the root folder of your webpage.

To do this,
You should go into your apache vhost file.
Here you can change the folder to include /apigility/public.
This way, the apigility ui is on / and the services you create are on /ping /....

The port does not matter.

A related question to this is: [How to change xampp localhost to another folder ( outside xampp folder)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847392/how-to-change-xampp-localhost-to-another-folder-outside-xampp-folder)