# Where is the "Index of /" page of Apache Localhost?

Tags: apache, xampp

I'm wondering if this page is configured in the Browser or if Apache defines it. Where can I find the file?

For clearity of what I mean, here's a Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You mean the one that you get when you have the directory listing setting in your apache conf?

Comment: This is configured in your httpd.conf (Apache configuration), and is the setting called `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change xampp localhost to another folder ( outside xampp folder)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847392/how-to-change-xampp-localhost-to-another-folder-outside-xampp-folder)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a page, Apache is just listing the directory content, it is not a HTML file being rendered.
The location you are seeing varies from installation to installation, but it is usually something like /var/www/htdocs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for contributing! This is not really a complete answer to the question - while it gives the OP an idea of what's going on, it's going to naturally result in several follow-on questions.  For example - how is this set? How would you change it?