# Creating new app with laravel/installer shows just file structure not website

Tags: php, laravel

I just decide to start learning Laravel. By following [Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation) most easy solution for me seems to be to start using laravel installer.

So what I did was installed installer globally and then simply created new project via `laravel new laravelapi`.

After cli prepare it I edited `.env` file with my database info and changed `APP_URL` to http://localhost/laravelapi/ (I'm using XAMPP and laravelapi is name of my project). Unfortunately when I opened browser on that URL I just see the files, not a rendered website.

[image]

Funny thing is that when i open `http://localhost/laravelapi/server.php` site load correctly (it's just some trivial laravel default page)

I was wondering if `htaccess` works correctly I tried to check if my apache has `mod_rewrite` as one of his loaded module but it was there. 
[image]

I am really new in it and I obviously missed something important, but I fight here with it for couple hours without any result. Does anyone face this issue before? If so what was the solution?

Comment: The document root of a Laravel project is the `public` directory: you need to modify your directory root. The `public/index.php` file is the entry point for your website: users should never be able to access anything outside of `public`.

Comment: index.php is in the public folder move to that directory or you may use the  serve Artisan command:`php artisan serve`

Comment: Thanks! It solve my issue. Feel free to add it as an answer to let me mark it as correct. Btw is there a way to easy change that? So root would be on `/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Document Root for a Laravel project is the `public` directory. All user requests should be routed to `public/index.php` unless the file requested exists within the `public` directory -- e.g: assets.

You can change the document root for an xampp operated project by following the steps provided in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847392/how-to-change-xampp-localhost-to-another-folder-outside-xampp-folder).

Answer (score 2):

You can create another `.htaccess` file in the main directory which will indicate that your project root is the PUBLIC folder. It will solve your problem.
you can try the sample code below.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not good practice to access project through "http://localhost/laravelapi/public"

Probably you will face problems for symbolic links or while hosting your project. It's good to have vHost for your PHP projects.

You can create a vhost for xampp and add document root upto the public directory of your project for Laravel, like as "../Project/laravelapi/public".

Also you can use inbuilt development server command as `php artisan serve`
which will start your server on "http://localhost:8000".

More helpful links 
1. Laravel Documentation - [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6)
2. vHost for Xampp - [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268205/how-to-create-virtual-host-on-xampp)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue were two reasons behind the error. 
one is not a proper `.htaccess` file placed in the root directory. 
other `php` version is not compatible with your laravel current version (low PHP version).

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue but I solved this problem. When we install Laravel then .htaccess file is in the public folder.

- Cut the .htaccess file from the public folder
- Paste this file in root folder of project

Comment: Why is this downvoted and it works? Make sure you restart apache once you have moved the file.