# Laravel did not serve but displays directories and folders

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.8. I just created a Laravel Application. When I wanted to serve it I used  **localhost:8888/smart-lms** .  It did not load the default page, but instead it displays folders and directories as shown below. What do I do please?

[image: laravel_error]

port: 8888
project: smart-lms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating new app with laravel/installer shows just file structure not website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883869/creating-new-app-with-laravel-installer-shows-just-file-structure-not-website)

Comment: Try to click the `public` folder

Comment: Check @Alex Harris dupe answer, it is the same question

Comment: Thanks. You solved the problem. I didn't take note of the public folder

Answer (score -1):

In your project directory, run `php artisan serve` in your command line